# How to update Cal-HeatMap?

Tags: d3.js

I am using Cal-HeatMap:

```
cal.init({
                      data: "data/datas.json",
                      domain: "day",                 // Group data by days
                      subDomain: "hour",             // Split each day by hours
                      range: 10,                     // Number of days to display
                      browsing: true,
                      cellSize: 15,
                      highlight: ["now"],
                      previousSelector: "#previousSelector-a-previous",
                      nextSelector: "#previousSelector-a-next",
                      subDomainTextFormat: function (date, value) {
                          return value;
                      },
                      onClick: function (date, count) {
                          alert("Oh gosh, " + count + " things occured on " + date.toISOString());
                      }
                  });
```

How can I update using JSON, I did this:

```
cal.update("data/datas.js");
              cal.options.data = "data/datas.json";
              cal.next();
```

I hit an error at:

```
var c=new Date(a.getFullYear(),a.getMonth(),a.getDate(),a.getHours())
```

Error:

```
Unable to get property for getFullYear()....
```

Comment: What is the variable `a`?

Comment: It would be useful to include a link to the complete source code you are using ( http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/ I assume). However, I can't find the specific line you say is your error in the source code.

Comment: I am using cal-heatmap v3.4.0. var c=new Date(a.getFullYear(),a.getMonth(),a.getDate(),a.getHours()) is in cal-heatmap.min.js

Comment: You're really expecting a lot from people giving a single line of code from a minimized library...  But from that I can tell you that the error is happening in the `getMinuteDomain` function or the `getHourDomain` function (line 2099 or line 2119 of the [full library](https://github.com/kamisama/cal-heatmap/blob/master/cal-heatmap.js)), and from that I can only assume that your passing in a value that is expected to be a date but that isn't.  Can't tell you much more than that without seeing a working example with your data format...